# PHP cookies and session

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm a new programmer and I'm just learning some PHP in terms of server programming. But I'm having a hard time understanding cookies and sessions. I'm currently working on this one exercise, and I need a little help with syntax and where everything would fall into place. Also, I'm not sure how to format the date needed and I need to  be sure my if statements are correct. Here are the official instructions for the first part I'm working on, followed by the code I have so far:

**login.php**

Use the login.php file to allow only registered users to log in (hard coded values for now). NOTE: Don’t ever in real life put the user and password information in a url variable!

-If they log-in correctly:
record that fact in a $_SESSION variable named ‘loggedIn’ with a value of ‘true’,

-set a cookie with a name of “loggedIn” and a value of the date and time (formatted like: January 25, 2015 10:00 am – use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for reference) that expires in 10 minutes and 
-then send them on to the admin.php.

-If they don’t log-in correctly print a message saying “Invalid Login”

-If they have logged in before (if the session variable exists), then simply re-direct them to the admin.php page

-They will provide their username and password via the URL:
kelvin.ist.rit.edu/~username/341/lab2/login.php?user=admin&password=password

-Use $_GET[‘user’] and $_GET[‘password’] to get the username and 
        password.

-If they don’t provide both values, display a message “Invalid Login”

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();


$username = "student";
$password = "student";

if(empty($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;

    $loggedIn = $_COOKIE['loggedIn'] = string date (string $format [, int 
        $timestamp = time()+600]); //expires 10 minutes from now

    header("Location: admin.php");
    exit;

} else {
    echo "<h2>Invalid Login</h2>";

}

if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    header("Location: admin.php");
    exit;

    $_GET['username'];
    $_GET['password'];

} else {
    echo "<h2>Invalid Login</h2>";

}


setcookie("test_cookie",$path, $domain, $loggedIn, $expire);

?>
```

Comment: Cookies and Sessions are not the same thing. Also, that is not the way you cast in PHP.

Comment: @system0verl0ad did I answer your question below? No up or down vote

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so excuse if there are any syntax errors but this should work. Cheers.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $message = null;

    if( isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 'true')
    {
        header("Location: admin.php");
        exit();
    }

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    {
        if( sizeof($_GET) && isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']) && $_GET['username'] && $_GET['password'])
        {
            if($_GET['username'] == 'username' && $_GET['password'] == '1234')
            {
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 'true';
                setcookie ("loggedIn", date("F d,Y h:ia"),  time()+60*10, "/", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
                header("Location: admin.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                $message = 'Invalid Login';
            }
        } else {
            $message = 'Invalid Login';
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php if($message) echo '<div class="warning">' . $message . '</div>'; ?>
        <form method="get">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="username" />

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="1234" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```